# What would be ideal way to share functionality between Rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a number of `view helpers` I use on almost every project, a set of useful `rake tasks`, minor extensions to `active record`, extensions to some gems (inherited_resources).

I'm wondering, what would be a good way to manage these 'snippets'? I wouldn't want to manage a gem for each snippet, or even a gem for each 'type' of snippet. Would it suffice to bundle this into a personal gem? Maybe add the option to specify which helpers/extensions to include in the project?

I could use a 'template' application which I could bundle with this code, but the problem here is if I update a snippet on one project, I want to be able to rollout that update on all projects with minimal effort (i.e. `bundle update`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your requirements, I would bundle it all in a `base-zenph-gem` and use it in every one o your projects, as it is the best way to have synchronized code over different projects.

Also, make a good documentation for it, as if anyone inherits one of those projects would love to know what is going on.

Comment: That is my other concern. Extracting this code into a gem will remove it from project files where it is defined explicitly. Would it be a good idea in this case to leave pointers to the gem within those files where the code would be expected?

Comment: I would just use great documentation, and maybe (as you said), make a note/comment where something related to the gem is being used

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a gem with Rails you can create an engine which contains reusable functionality, then you can specify the use of the engine within your applications.

You can read more about it in the Rails documentation: [Rails Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)